# What is the name of this machine and what is it used for?

Tags: ice-cream

I am looking to identify the below machine from a video I watched on youtube.

I suspect it is used somehow in the process of making ice cream.

I was looking in the pasteurizing category without any success.

Any idea?

Thank you!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you add a link to the video?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's just a commercial version of the machine we normally call an *ice cream maker*.

Even some of the home machines have a similar armature structure to hold the motor over the mixing container:

[image]

Its function is to stir the mixture as it freezes to aerate it and prevent large ice crystals from forming.

Comment: Calling it an "ice cream churn" would also be understood in some regions I guess...